# Automating a series of similar operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a series of input fields representing Items. The corresponding html looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="items[][name]" id="items__name" value="" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="items[][description]" id="items__description" value="" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="items[][rate]" id="items__rate" value="" class="form-control calc">
<input type="text" name="items[][quantity]" id="items__quantity" value="" class="form-control calc">
```

Now user can add items. For that, I just clone the wrapper of above fields and add at the last of the items table.

So, now I have an array of freshly added text fields. referenced as `textFields`, to which I need to add validation rules. I am using `jQuery Validator` for validation.

My code for that looks like this:

```
           $(textFields[0]).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: I18n.t('orders.itemNameRequired')
                }
            });

            $(textFields[1]).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: I18n.t('orders.itemDescriptionRequired')
                }
            });

            $(textFields[2]).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                messages: {
                    required: I18n.t('orders.itemRateRequired'),
                    number: I18n.t('orders.itemRateInvalid')
                }
            });

            $(textFields[3]).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                messages: {
                    required: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityRequired'),
                    number: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityInvalid')
                }
            });
```

Now, it works fine. But is there a way to DRY it up by using a loop or storing the rules in a hash or somewhere like that? Can't think of a way. Need a second person's perspective here!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over the element when they are created?  I'm asking because you could put relevant information into data attributes for each element and then draw from them when adding the rules.  That would make a generic function a lot simpler.

Comment: If each textField needs custom configuration, then it would be more maintainable to reference each one with a specific name rather than iterate through them by index. I can see the desire to automate the code if you have 20+ different fields, but less than that you should favor being explicit over trying to be clever.

Comment: @Archer edited my question, is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, that's great.  I'll update my answer to suit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally do something like this to tidy the code...

```
function addRule(element, number, messages) {
    $(element).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        number: number,
        messages: messages
    });
}

addRule(textFields[0], false, {
    required: I18n.t('orders.itemNameRequired')
});

addRule(textFields[1], false, {
    required: I18n.t('orders.itemDescriptionRequired')
});

addRule(textFields[2], true, {
    required: I18n.t('orders.itemRateRequired'),
    number: I18n.t('orders.itemRateInvalid')
});

addRule(textFields[3], true, {
    required: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityRequired'),
    number: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityInvalid')
});
```

However, for the html you've supplied this following script will add the rules as required for those fields...

```
$("input[name]").each(function() {
    var rule = {
        required: true,
        messages: {}
    };

    if (this.name.match("[name]").length) {
        rule.messages.required = I18n.t('orders.itemNameRequired');
    }
    else if (this.name.match("[description]").length) {
        rule.messages.required = I18n.t('orders.itemDescriptionRequired');
    }
    else if (this.name.match("[rate]").length) {
        rule.number = true;
        rule.messages.required = I18n.t('orders.itemRateRequired');
        rule.messages.number = I18n.t('orders.itemRateInvalid');
    }
    else if (this.name.match("[quantity]").length) {
        rule.number = true;
        rule.messages.required = I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityRequired');
        rule.messages.number = I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityInvalid');
    }

    $(this).rules("add", rule);
});
```

The advantage with the 2nd approach is that you could add as many name, description, rate and quantity fields as you liked to a page and that would apply the validation to all of them without needing to be changed.  Either approach will work, so it's just a case of choosing which one suits the given scenario best.

Comment: I do have control on adding the elements. What would your approach been then?

Comment: If you can show the markup for one of the number inputs then I'll modify this to suit, and ad-lib the other fields.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  You already had relevant info in the element tags to do what I had in mind, so I just used that instead.  No need to modify the markup for that to work.

Comment: I think use of `indexOf` would be more suited instead of `match`. What's ur say @Archer?

Comment: It makes no difference to the end result.  I like the use of `.length` as a boolean, but if you prefer `!= -1` then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't significantly reduce lines of code but you can use an array of the rules config objects and loop over elements to add from array. It would allow some separation of business logic and config data if needed though

```
var fieldOpts = [{
    messages: {
        required: I18n.t('orders.itemNameRequired')
    }
}, {    
    messages: {
        required: I18n.t('orders.itemDescriptionRequired')
    }
}, {    
    number: true,
    messages: {
        required: I18n.t('orders.itemRateRequired'),
        number: I18n.t('orders.itemRateInvalid')
    }
}, {    
    number: true,
    messages: {
        required: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityRequired'),
        number: I18n.t('orders.itemQuantityInvalid')
    }
}]

$(textFields).each(function(i){
    var rules = fieldOpts[i];
    rules.required=true; // common to all so am adding here instead of in array
    $(this).rules('add',rules)
});
```

note also that if all fields will be required can put `required` attribute on elements

Comment: Had a similar code in mind. But then it seemed like dumping a mess in a different place?

Comment: Gets a bit subjective for sure. Not sure there really is a `best` solution and it really boils down to code style preference

Comment: @abhinavmsra, I'm not really sure what you expect.  You're trying to reduce repetitive code where almost none of it is actually repeating.  Like it's been suggested, you can put some of this within the markup... use the `required="required"` attribute on the dynamic `input` and the plugin will pick it up.  Otherwise, for unique messages on dynamic fields, you'll have to call `.rules()` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine but you need to store `i18n` messages in the attributes of the very input fields. like

`<input name="my_field" data-i18n-number-messages="This is a required field" />`

`<input name="my_field" data-i18n-required-messages="This is a required field" data-i18n-number-messages="This is a required field" />`
Since you are cloning the pre-existing fields you only need to add the message once in compile time/backend.

Code:

```
function addRule(targetHash){
        $.each(targetHash, function (element, options){
            var $element = $('input[name="' + element + '"]');
            var methods = {}
            var messages = {}
            $.each(options, function(method, trueFalse){
                methods[method] = trueFalse;
                if (trueFalse){
                    messages[method] = $element.attr('data-i18n-' + method + '-messages');
                }
            });
            var rules = $.extend({}, methods, {messages: messages});
            console.log(rules);
            $element.rules('add', rules);
        });
    }

    addRule({
        // textFields[3] should be the name of the fields
        'textFields[3]': {required: true, number: true},                
        'textFields[4]': {required: true}
    });
```

Comment: the solution is indeed the most compact. But how to handle the case of multiple validation messages?

Answer (score -1):

Provide class to numeric field Let's say it is numeric-field.
Here is just pseudo-code to do this.

```
$("#input-container :input").each(function(){

  if(this.hasClass('numeric-field'){
    this.rules('add', {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            messages: {
                required: I18n.t('orders.itemRateRequired'),
                number: I18n.t('orders.itemRateInvalid')
            }
        });
   }
 else{
      this.rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: I18n.t('orders.itemDescriptionRequired')
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: How to deal with messages in this case?

Comment: Every rule is different.  Look at the values in the `required` and `number` properties.

Comment: You've not looked at the code in the question properly.  Your code will give incorrect validation results.  Just look at these values in the question... `orders.itemNameRequired`, `orders.itemDescriptionRequired`, `orders.itemRateRequired`, `orders.itemQuantityRequired`

Comment: I know, which is why I explained why it's wrong a little clearer.

Comment: this would end up being more cumbersome than what OP had originally. It doesn't match ...so you would need more conditionals